# Set specific layouts files in ZF2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I want built my ZF2 source to get specific layouts by module hierarchy

Then if the templates file exists, i want map it to current module

Ex:

- templates/album/profile/list.phtml : Module "Album" => Controller "Profile" => Action "List"
- templates/album/album.phtml : For all "Album" module
- templates/layout/layout.phtml : Default template for another module

======================================

I got this in ZF2 Skeleton Apps

```
'view_manager' => array (
            'display_not_found_reason' => true,
            'display_exceptions' => true,
            'doctype' => 'HTML5',
            'not_found_template' => 'error/404',
            'exception_template' => 'error/index',
            'template_map' => array (
                    'layout/layout' => __DIR__ . '/../../../template/layout/layout.phtml',
                    'layout/custom' => __DIR__ . '/../../../template/layout/custom.phtml',
                    'error/404' => __DIR__ . '/../../../template/error/404.phtml',
                    'error/index' => __DIR__ . '/../../../template/error/index.phtml' 
            ),
            'template_path_stack' => array (
                    __DIR__ . '/../view' 
            ) 
    )
```

I can set custom layout by this way

```
$e->getApplication()->getEventManager()->getSharedManager()->attach('Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController', 'dispatch', function($e) {
        $controller = $e->getTarget();
        $controller->layout('layout/custom');
}
```

But i must define 'template_map' manually. Is there any ways to set current controller specific template file ? I want something like this

```
//Set template
$template = 'layout/layout';
if (file_exists($templatePath . $currAction.'.phtml')) {
    $template = $currAction;
}else if(file_exists($templatePath . $currController.'.phtml')) {
    $template = $currController;
}else if(file_exists($templatePath . $currModule.'.phtml')) {
    $template = $currModule;
}else{
    //return default template
}

$controller->layout($template);
```

Thanks

================

Update 11/27/2012 :

I found some simple way to map layout key:

In module.config.php just adding an addition path

```
'view_manager' => array (
    .....
    'template_path_stack' => array (
            __DIR__ . '/../view/',
            __DIR__ . '/../../../template/'
    ) 
)
```

Then i can use template hierarchy system. BUT only for module and controller level. My problem is the layout and "action view" conflict

- /template/album.phtml => work fine. Apply template all "album" module
- /template/album/profile.phtml => work fine. Apply template all "album/profile" controller
- /template/album/profile/detail.phtml => It's conflict with "modules/album/view/album/profile/detail.phtml" . Then it's got wrong view by set layout file to view

Comment: You worked out that layout switcher already? I am looking for something similar but a switcher based on domain name (websiteA.com/websiteB.com)

Comment: Not yet. I still have some issue with this ( I've created new question). About your domain switcher you can try multiple public folder, then you can point this to their own template,module, library .etc... Please take a look my old project ( base on ZF1 ) http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/812/1242012123937am.jpg/. It's not best solution but i hope it can help